# Embeded Twitter Link Showing Up Above Hamburger Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu

I am building a website for a college class and I've run into a problem. I can't seem to find the answer when I google it, so I made an account to post it here. I hope that someone is able to identify what is going on.

[image: Here is an image of the problem in action]

As you can see, the embedded twitter post is showing up on top of the hamburger menu and I'm not sure how to get it underneath.

Here is the HTML (It's still a work in progress and I'm pretty new so please forgive me for any ugly code):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/run.png">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="weatherBar" class="weatherBar">
            <button class="hamburger">&#9776;</button>
            <button class="cross">&#735;</button>
            <nav class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#events">About the Events</a>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li><a href="#starting">Starting Times</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Course Details</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">What to Bring</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Upcoming Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Registration</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Packet Pick Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="socialLinks">
                <a href="#"><img src="images/fb-ico.png" alt="" class="iconHeight"></a>&nbsp;
                <a href="#"><img src="images/twit-ico.png" alt="" class="iconHeight"></a>&nbsp;
                <a href="#"><img src="images/inst-ico.png" alt="" class="iconHeight"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main class="wrapper">
        <div id="details" class="details lightSub contentFill contentPad">
            <h2 class="subHeader">What People are Saying</h2>
            <div class="sub_head_line_white"></div>
            <div class="socialWrapper centering">
                <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fcas222cascade%2Fposts%2F366912850439109&width=350&show_text=true&height=214&appId" width="350" height="214" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="socialWrapper centering">
                <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Fantastic weather for training! Can&#39;t wait to get in the water for open water swims!</p>&mdash; CAS 222 (@pcccas222) <a href="https://twitter.com/pcccas222/status/994599695136653312?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">May 10, 2018</a></blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer></footer>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ham.js"></script>
    <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $(".cross").hide();

    $(".menu").hide();

    $(".hamburger").show();

    $(".hamburger").on("click", function () {
        $(".menu").slideToggle("slow");
        $(".hamburger").hide();
        $(".cross").show();
    });

    $(".cross").on("click", function () {
        $(".menu").slideToggle("slow");
        $(".cross").hide();
        $(".hamburger").show();
    });

    $(".menu a").on("click", function () {
        $(".menu").slideToggle("slow");
        $(".cross").hide();
        $(".hamburger").show();
    });


});
```

Here is the CSS:

Menu.css

```
.hamburger {
    background: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    line-height: 35px;
    color: red;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: 700;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    z-index: 10;
}

.cross {
    background: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: red;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height: 55px;
    font-weight: 700;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    z-index: 10;
}

.socialLinks {
    background: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 8px;
    right: 10px;
    color: red;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    z-index: 10;
    }

.iconHeight {
    height: 20px;
}

.menu {
/*    z-index: 10;*/
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0, .85);
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    right: 0;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    z-index: 10;
}



.menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.menu li {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 0;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
}

.menu li:hover {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 0;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    color: red;
}

.menu ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
}

.menu ul a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
}

.menu ul a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.menu ul a:visted {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: gray;
}

.submenu li {
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

style.css

```
body {
    .grayGradient;
}
main {}
.hero {

    background-image: url(../images/run3.jpg);
    background-size: auto;
    background-position: center;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}
.heroBot {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #000;
}

.weatherBar {
    position: fixed;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    border-bottom: 3px red solid;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

footer {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    border-top: 3px red solid;
}
h1 {
    .fontOswald;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.headerSize {
    font-size: 50px;
    .fontNarrow;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.titleDiv {
    padding-left: 15px;
    width: 95%;
    padding-top: 40px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-right: 15px;
    border-bottom: 3px red solid;

}
.titleText {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.disc {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    .fontBaseText;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: lighter;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.facebookFeed {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}

.contentPad {
    padding: 20px 20px 45px 20px;
}

.contentFill p {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    .fontBaseText;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.subHeader {
    .fontNarrow;
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
.subHeaderAlt {
    .fontNarrow;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    color: #fff;
}

.sub_head_line {
    height: 5px;
    width: 95%;
    .grayGradientBtR;
}

.sub_head_line_white {
    height: 5px;
    width: 95%;
    .grayGradientWtR;
}


.darkSub {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}

.lightSub {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

.tableDay {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    .fontNarrow;
}

.timesTable {
    margin: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    align-content: center;
    .fontBaseText;
}

.timesTable tr:first-child {
    border: none;
}
.timesTable tr {
    border-left: 2px @mainRed solid;
    border-right: 2px @mainRed solid;
}

.timesTable table,
tr,
td,
th {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 3px;
}



.timesTable th {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px;
}
.timesTable td {
    padding: 10px;
}

.timesTable tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: @darkGray;
}

.raceName {
    width: 180px;
}

.raceTime {
    width: 100px;
}
.startingTimeTableWrapper {
    width: 100%;
}

.centering {
    .marginCenter;
}

.socialWrapper {
    width: 350px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.subHeader:before {
    height: 25px;
    display: block;
    content: '';
}
.subHeaderAlt:before {
    height: 25px;
    display: block;
    content: '';
}
```

Comment: The css is main part of your problem which is missing.

Comment: Oh thank you! I just added it!

Comment: I can't get it to replicate the error, so I've removed my answer.